Clickonce app not opening once closed after 30 minutes on windows server 2019 standard
I have deployed an app via ClickOnce.
The app is downloading from deployed URL and successfully installed.
When I open the app first time, it opens and works great. But if I close the app after 30 minutes and open it again, the app is not opening. If I click on setup (the installer) the app opens or if I reinstall the app, then also opens but not opening from app icon on the desktop.
I searched many articles on the internet but nothing found related to my issue.
only this article seems to be linked with my issue.

If  checking through the Event Viewer, are there any errors?

no, there are no errors.

Is the app deployed under an administrator account?

Can you provide detailed steps to reproduce the problem? Does this problem occur in all clickonce apps?

I faced this problem only in windows server 2019.
My app is checking automatic updates via clickonce at application starts and will update if available.
To reproduce you have to open the app on Windows Server and close it after 30-40 minutes and then if you want to reopen it's not opening.

I resolved the issue by disabling the automatic app checkup at the start of the application via ClickOnce.
Implemented own update checker using ClickOnce libraries. Now my app check for updates every 5 minutes after app opening.
For update checker I took help from visual studio community:
Note: The clickonce popup before app opening is causing issue which I think windows server block sometimes.
